# Getting index of cursor-selected text

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>This </span>
    <span>is </span>
    <span>plain </span>
    <span>text </span>
    <span>and </span>
    <span>this </span>
    <span>is </span>
    <span>more </span>
    <span>plain </span>
    <span>text </span>
    <span>and </span>
    <span>this </span>
    <span>is </span>
    <span>the </span>
    <span>final </span>
    <span>plain </span> 
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

That displays as:

> This is plain text and this is more plain text and this is the final
>   plain text

*Pleas note: the `<span>` tags are being used for another purpose.*

I want to be able to highlight (cursor select) any part of the above text and get both the start & end index of the cursor selected text. For example, the following cursor selection (cursor-selecting the second occurence of the term *"plain text"*) would output `startIndex = 35` and `endIndex = 44`

[image]

What has been tried & ideas:

- Right now I am getting the cursor selected text using `var text = window.getSelection().toString();`
- Using functions such as `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` doesn't appear to be an option as the cursor selected term can be arbitrary and thus there is no pattern, and there is no guarantee that it will be unique.
- I recently posted a very similar question which was marked as a duplicate, because there is a solution to this problem (using `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`), but for that to work you have to use a `<textarea>` which isn't possible for this use case.
- I feel as though perhaps the odd use of `<span>` tags could be utilised in some way; particularly because it's an option to add any `id`s (or other attributes) as necessary.

Restriction:

- Using a `<textarea>` instead of a `<div>` is not an option for this scenario.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is? What is the expected result?

Comment: The start and end indices of the cursor-selected term relative to the entire string. If I have the string `"hello Bob, hello Bill"` and I cursor-select the second `"hello"` then the result should be `startIndex = 10` and `endIndex = 14`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to interrogate the various properties of the [selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) returned by `getSelection()`.

Of particular interest to you are:

- `anchorNode` - the element the selection began on
- `anchorOffset` - the index of the character within `anchorNode` the selection began at
- `focusNode` - the element the selection ended on
- `focusOffset` - the index of the character within `focusNode` the selection ended at

It's then a case of doing DOM iteration and some maths.

Putting it together:

```
let div = document.querySelector('div'),
    text = div.innerText;
div.addEventListener('mouseup', evt => {
    let sel = getSelection(),
        result = {start: null, end: null};
    if (!sel) return;
    ['start', 'end'].forEach(which => {
        let counter = 1,
            tmpNode = div.querySelector('span'),
            node = which == 'start' ? 'anchor' : 'focus';
        while(tmpNode !== sel[node+'Node'].parentElement) {
            result[which] += tmpNode.innerText.length;
            counter++;
            tmpNode = div.querySelector('span:nth-child('+counter+')')
        }
        result[which] += sel[node+'Offset'] + (which == 'start' ? 1 : 0);
    });
    alert('Selection starts at '+result.start+' and ends at '+result.end);
}, false);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lvp2otq/1/)